# Reading from SerialPort; Error when I close and then open application

Tags: c#, serial-port

I created application for reading from Serial Port and it works just fine. But the problem occure when I close the application and run it again. Suddenly reading from Serial port stops working. I have to disconnect and connect USB to fix that.

This is my code:

```
namespace Serial
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        SerialPort mainSerialPort = new SerialPort();

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            mainSerialPort.PortName = "COM" + numericPort.Value.ToString();
            mainSerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mainSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mainSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mainSerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mainSerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mainSerialPort.DataReceived += DataReceived_Read;

            try{
                mainSerialPort.Open();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                labelStatus.Text = ex.GetType().ToString();
            }


            if (mainSerialPort.IsOpen == true){
                numericPort.BackColor = Color.Green;
                labelStatus.Text = "Port je otevřen!";
            }else{
                numericPort.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

        }

        private void DataReceived_Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort mySerial = (SerialPort)sender;

            if (this.InvokeRequired){
                listBoxRead.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                    listBoxRead.Items.Add(mySerial.ReadExisting());
                    listBoxRead.SelectedIndex = listBoxRead.Items.Count - 1;
                }));
            }

        }

        private void Main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainSerialPort.DataReceived -= DataReceived_Read;
            mainSerialPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You **must** set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to true yourself if you don't use handshaking.  A serial device pays attention to those signals and refuses to send anything when they are off.

Answer (score 0):

USB and serial ports are unmanaged ressources. You have to dispose it!. A simple "Close" on FormClosed will not do the same.

Comment: Close() and Dispose() do the **exact** same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with some resources not properly freed up. Try calling Dispose method

```
mainSerialPort.Close();
mainSerialPort.Dispose();
```

Comment: I tryed to Dispose it and still nothing :(